# cmake, boost locale and a static library

Tags: boost, cmake, static-libraries, po, boost-locale

I have two applications and a static library used by both.

All three using CMake as build system.

I want to localize my applications.

I more or less understand how to localize applications but I'm not
sure how I should localize my static library.

If it would be a dynamic library I could install the compiled
translations alongside with the binary and access them.

But a static library is only relevant for the developer. There is no longer a
library in the final product. I would somehow need to transfer the compiled
translations of the library to the applications.

When calling make install for one of my applications the translatons of my
static library needs to be installed, too.

How can I achieve something like this using CMake?

Comment: what do you mean by "a static library used by both" application ?  Are those application are have been linked against this static library? Than you don't need it in the execution time. If it is still needed, than it isn't a static library. If you want to achieve that your "library" being installed along side your application, you need to use [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html) command in cmake.